# How can I add more TTYs to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tty

The question is basically the title. I tried <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> but nothing happens. I use all six of my currently available virtual terminals and need more. How can I add more TTYs?

Comment: Have you considered terminal multiplexer like `tmux` ([link](https://tmux.github.io/))? Few years ago I would ask your question myself. Now I feel naked without `tmux`.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 16.04 per default uses systemd. So you could could e.g. set

```
NAutoVTs=10
ReserveVT=10
```

in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to increase the number of ttys to 10.

However, as Kamil suggested, you might want to use a tool like `tmux`or `screen` to multiplex terminals.